# How to write a loop that does something different in the last iteration?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

The output for the given program should be 1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8.
However, mine keeps giving me 1--2--3--4--5--6--7-8--.I need to get rid of "--" after 8, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Could someone help me, please?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc 
.data

arrayb byte 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
space byte "--",0

.code
main PROC
    mov eax,0
    mov edx,offset space
    mov esi,offset arrayb

    mov ecx, 8      

    printb:

         mov al, [esi]
         call writedec
         call writestring
         inc esi
         mov eax, 8

    loop printb

exit
main ENDP

end main
```

Comment: All code needs to be posted here directly as text.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, it's not searchable and we can't copy/paste into an answer.

Comment: If you don't want `space` to be printed on the last iteration then you need to add a check and conditional branch for that.

Comment: @Michael: Or better: peel that last special-case iteration.  Put a `call writedec` after the loop branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code (and loop specifically) currently does:

```
<init state>
counter = 8
printb:
  output number
  output "--"
  loop to printb
<exit>
```

If you run through it in your head, it should be obvious why "--" is printed after last number.

There are many ways how to adjust that code, in real world code doing formatting I often either use some kind of `join` function which takes list and separator, and produces the formatted string, or if doing it manually, I would probably hardcode output of "1" ahead of loop, initialize the state to start loop as if starting from "2", and output "--" as first thing in the loop, i.e.:

```
<init state>
output number
advance state as if it was printed inside loop
counter = 8-1   ; one value is already out
printb:
  output "--"   ; the loop body starts with "--" output
  output number
  loop to printb
<exit>
```

I.e. in your code (with some modifications "improving" some things I didn't like :

```
...
mov   edx,offset space
mov   esi,offset arrayb
movzx eax, BYTE PTR [esi]
inc   esi
call  writedec
mov   ecx, 8-1

printb:
    call  writestring
    movzx eax, BYTE PTR [esi]
    inc   esi
    call  writedec
loop printb
exit
...
```

---

edit

The Peter Cordes idea from comments to make last item special case would maybe lead to better code in generic cases, where the amount of items is variable (with "8" fixed you know you can display first element and then 7 more will be looped).

Let's imagine such function in assembly, taking arguments in registers:

```
; esi = byte array to output
; ecx = amount of bytes
; will modify eax, ecx, edx, esi
OutputByteArray PROC
    jecxz   NoItemsToOutput     ; if ecx=0
    dec     ecx
    jz      OutputLastItem      ; if ecx=1, display only last item
    ; 1 < count, so "0 < ecx" here (ecx = count-1) => do the loop
    mov     edx,offset space
printb:     ; output number and "--" "count-1" times
        movzx eax, BYTE PTR [esi]
        inc   esi
        call  writedec
        call  writestring
    loop    printb
OutputLastItem:
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esi]
    call    writedec
NoItemsToOutput:
    ret
ENDP
```